# Как сделать смену абзацев в WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как сделать, что бы в wordpress можно было менять абзацы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. вот на странице есть какой-то текст, надо сделать его динамичным. Как реализовать через CMS WordPress?

Comment: Динамика - это движение. Прыгать они, что ли должны? Полагаю, вопрос не в том, хотя из скриншота понять что-то невозможно. Скорее всего, вопрос в том, как сделать абзацы с разными стилями. Если да, то ответ - стилями css и сделать. Добавить нужный класс к каждому абзацу и прописать классы в css.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Вопрос в том, как сделать что бы текст в этих абзацах менять можно было

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: Каким образом сейчас реализована эта страница?

Comment: >Вопрос в том, как сделать что бы текст в этих абзацах менять можно было. 
По какой логике? Откуда тексты должны браться?